# Have NMock2 to create instance of a Type

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, nmock2

I have this situation:

A method that expects a `Type` as one of its parameter;
This `Type` must be a `Type` that implements an `Interface` in the project;
I need to write tests for this method;
I'm using **NMock2**;

Is there any way to get a Type from NMock2 so I can use it as a parameter of this method instead of create an implementation of this interface?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this type that you talk about already implement the interface you are interested in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer using [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), but from what I can see, you should be able to retrieve a fake and use it like follows:

```
var mocks = new Mockery();
var someFakeType = mocks.NewMock<ISomeType>();

// do whatever you need to setup this fake
// such as setting expectations, stubing properties or methods, etc

var someObject = new SomeObject();
someObject.MethodUnderTest(someFakeType);
```